# How can i create a new row on a table in HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a new row using a `javascript` function. I've already reviewed all of the of the previously answered questions but non of them helped. this is my code if this helps out any:

```
var deleteRow = document.getElementsByClassName('gone');

function removeParent(){
  this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}

for(var i = 0; i < deleteRow.length; i++) {
  deleteRow[i].addEventListener("click", removeParent);
}

var addRow = document.getElementsByClassName('add');

function addRow(){
  var deleteRow = table.insertRow(0);
}

for(var i = 0; i < addRow.length; i++) {
  addRow[i].addEventListener("click", addRow);
}
```

Comment: use jquery, this will make things easy

Comment: The problem is I haven't used jquery, I have no experience in it yet @mapodev

Comment: Is there no way to do it with just a basic Javascript code ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `code`

```
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
}
```

And use this `html`

```
<p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Row2 cell1</td>
      <td>Row2 cell2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Row3 cell1</td>
      <td>Row3 cell2</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Endrit Shala but this didn't work this is the same example from w3 school if you take a look at my code you can see the way i did it before, this code didn't work with my code.

Comment: First function needs to be named `myCreateFunction` not `myFunction` to match `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @DivineComedian Thank you that you told me.

Comment: @Villainy Well what you're asking this is what you have to do maybe try to change the question because you want something else.